# MvvmCross & MvxAdapter & Polymorphic Types with custom controls

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently trying to implement my own version of the polymorphic types demo that is located here:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections

And I have it working as the demo shows.  However, I am looking to extend that demo to have more complex controls inside of the MvxListView.   I am wanting to have each of the list items control a fragment that has a View and a core ViewModel for additional processing.

I am unsure of the correct way of implementing this.

The code that I am using to create the custom view is this:

```
        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, Object source, Int32 templateId)
    {
        var listItem = (TodayPanel) source;

        if (listItem != null)
            templateId = (Int32) typeof (Resource.Layout).GetField(listItem.View).GetValue(null);

        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
    }
```

As always, it's probably something simple that I am missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain 1 what your viewmodel list is (your code suggests it is a list of TodayPanel objects?) and 2 an example of what you mean by fragment inside the list view item. Happy to try to help - but don't understand at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate it when this happens, but after posting my question, I stepped away from the computer for a little bit and started to do something else.   At that point, everything clicked into place.   Stuart, in response to your question, the TodayPanel was NOT an MvxModelView, and therein was the crux of the problem.  What I was doing was passing a list of TodayPanels into the listview, which was an SQLite entity object and not an MvxModelView object.

For others that might be struggling with this, I am going to post my solution here.

So here is what I ended up doing.   I first created a class for each of the TodayPanel entity objects that inherited from an abstract base class that inherited from MvxModelView.

```
public abstract class TodayBaseViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    protected TodayViewModel TodayViewModel { get; set; }
    protected IDataService DataService { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public Boolean CanHide { get; set; }
    public Boolean Visible { get; set; }
    public Int32 SortOrder { get; set; }
    public String View { get; set; }

    protected abstract void SetEventHandlers();

    protected BaseViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        DataService = dataService;
    }

    public void Init(TodayViewModel todayViewModel)
    {
        TodayViewModel = todayViewModel;

        SetEventHandlers();
    }
}
```

I made it abstract as I wanted 0 or more event handlers to be attached in the final class. which is done through the abstract SetEventHandlers() method:

```
public class CoachSaysViewModel : TodayBaseViewModel
{
    public CoachSaysViewModel(IDataService dataService)
        : base(dataService)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetEventHandlers()
    {
        TodayViewModel.ConnectionUpdated += TodayViewModelConnectionUpdated;
        TodayViewModel.NewActivityReceived += TodayViewModelNewActivityReceived;
    }

    protected void TodayViewModelNewActivityReceived(Object sender, EventArgs.ActivityReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TodayViewModelConnectionUpdated(Object sender, EventArgs.ConnectionUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Then I created an extension method that converts the TodayPanel entity to one of the classes that inherits from TodayBaseViewModel.

```
     public static BaseViewModel ToBaseViewModel(this TodayPanel todayPanel, TodayViewModel todayViewModel)
    {
        BaseViewModel model = null;

        switch (todayPanel.View)
        {
            case "Today_QuickView":
                model = Mvx.IocConstruct<QuickViewViewModel>();
                break;

            case "Today_CoachSays":
                model = Mvx.IocConstruct<CoachSaysViewModel>();
                break;
        }

        if (model == null)
            return null;

        model.CanHide = todayPanel.CanHide;
        model.Name = todayPanel.Name;
        model.SortOrder = todayPanel.SortOrder;
        model.Title = todayPanel.Title;
        model.View = todayPanel.View;
        model.Visible = todayPanel.Visible;

        model.Init(todayViewModel);

        return model;
    }
```

That then allowed me to create a list of MvxViewModels that are then bound to the MvxListView and hence are allowed to do the additional processing that I am wanting to do.

I'm sure that there are some improvements that I can do to the end result, and if you see anything feel free to point it out.  :)